# C++ : Function return String in Static Library give Error : expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before ':' token

Tags: c++, string, function, return

Hi Team i'm leaning how to create a static library in C++, unfortunately my code below is giving headache, even after google for some hours i cant find the problem where is. follows a lot of suggestion with no success.

ercisstaticlib.h

```
#ifndef __ERCISSTATICLIB__
#define __ERCISSTATICLIB__
#include <string>

extern "C" std::string GetDatabaseName() ;

#endif  // ERCISSTATICLIB_H_INCLUDED
```

main.cpp

```
std::string GetDatabaseName()
{
    return "Testing";
}
```

error message

```
=== Build: Debug in ErcisLib (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before ':' token
=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===
```

Comment: Are you compiling it with `gcc`? C++ frontend is called `g++`.

Comment: Hi i'm using Code::Block with GNU GCC compiler. my main file has extension of "c", i have tried to change to "cpp" to  but still geting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string` is a class.

`extern c`  support only C types, because it cause the function to have a C signature.

C signature means no classes, since there is no classes in C, only in C++.

you should use:

```
extern "C" const char* GetDatabaseName() ;
```

but you need to be careful not to return pointer to local variable.

You have other option: you can gave up the `extern "C"` and keep use:

```
std::string GetDatabaseName();
```

if you are going to link your lib with C++, there is no reason to use `extern c`. But if you need to link with C, you should choose the first option.